# How do I write code to avoid error when windows service read config file?

Tags: python, windows, service, config

I have file tree:

```
f:/src/
   restore.ini
   config.py
   log.py
   service.py
   test.py
```

the `test.py` code like this:

```
import service
import log
import config

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

    def setUp(self):
        self.currentRound = int(config.read_config_co(r'restore.ini', 'Record')['currentRound'])

    def testAction(self):
        log.info(self.currentRound)

    def tearDown(self):
        config.write_config_update_co(self.currentRound-1, 'Record', 'currentRound', r'restore.ini')


class PerfServiceThread(service.NTServiceThread):

    def run (self):
        while self.notifyEvent.isSet():
            try:
                test = Test()
                test.setUp()
                test.testAction()
                test.tearDown()
            except:
                import traceback
                log.info(traceback.format_exc())


class PerfService(pywinservice.NTService):
    _svc_name_ = 'myservice'
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service"
    _svc_description_ = "This is what My Service does"
    _svc_thread_class = PerfServiceThread


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pywinservice.handleCommandLine(PerfService)
```

Now, I use cmdline `python test.py install` and `python test.py start` to action service, but error.

If I move  all files in directory `src` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\src`, and change code:

```
self.currentRound = int(config.read_config_co(r'src\restore.ini', 'Record')['currentRound'])

config.write_config_update_co(self.currentRound-1, 'Record', 'currentRound', r'src\restore.ini')
```

Now, it's OK!

I want not move directory `src`, how do I do? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use relative paths for file or directory names python will look for them (or create them) in your current working directory (the $PWD variable in bash; something similar on windows?).

if you want to have them relative to the current python file, you can use (python 3.4)

```
from pathlib import Path
HERE = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
RESTORE_INI = HERE / 'restore.ini'
```

or (python 2.7)

```
import os.path
HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
RESTORE_INI = os.path.join(HERE, 'restore.ini')
```

if your `restore.ini` file lives in the same directory as your python script.

then you can use that in

```
def setUp(self):
    self.currentRound = int(config.read_config_co(RESTORE_INI, 
                           'Record')['currentRound'])
```

Comment: hi, hiro, should be `os.path.join(HERE, 'restore.ini')`.